# Php exec or shell_exec() run a process that runs another process

Tags: php, process, exec

Im trying to run a process via php with exec() function.The code works perfectly fine and the application itself.But somehow when the process tries to run another process it fails.So for my main application once it is started (main.exe) then it tries to start (engine.exe) but fails.I see the "main.exe" process in the Task Manager but no "engine.exe".So this is basically starting a process with child processes.

Windows Server 2012 Database , running IIS 8 and php 5.4.

Here's the Php code :

```
$executing = exec("C:\\test\\main.exe 1 World");
```

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with main.exe. Does the user running main.exe (the web server user) have access to run engine.exe as well?

Comment: Does it have to?I gave all permisions to the folder and the engine.exe.How does php exec works.Does it runs the process in some kind of virtual enviroment or just ask Windows to run it.

Comment: on windows, it just makes a call to `cmd.exe /c {your command}`. But that will essentially run as whatever user is making the call. So whatever user the webserver is running under. If either program requires special permissions or admin privileges or anything like that, it will likely just fail and not run.

Comment: Just for the test i changed my IIS use to Administrator and give all permisions to all files that im using.Every program i run it runs perfectly fine.I will try disabling UAC and all other security

Comment: That is colossally bad idea. Even giving the web server user admin is horrible. If your site gets hacked in any way you are just giving the hacker full admin rights on your computer. Ideally the webserver would have no permissions except read so it can parse scripts and nothing else.

Comment: Yes i know.Im running the server inside VMware workstation.Once im going to publish it im gonna patch that security holes but for now i was just curious if this problem is from permissions